# Select single row per unique field value with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have thousands of rows of data, a segment of which looks like:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------+  
| Customer ID |  Company  | Sales |  
+-------------+-----------+-------+  
|    45678293 | Sears     |    45 |  
|    01928573 | Walmart   |     6 |  
|    29385068 | Fortinoes |     2 |  
|    49582015 | Walmart   |     1 |  
|    49582015 | Joe's     |     1 |  
|    19285740 | Target    |    56 |  
|    39506783 | Target    |     4 |  
|    39506783 | H&M       |     4 |  
+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

In every case that a customer ID occurs more than once, the value in 'Sales' is also the same but the value in 'Company' is different (this is true throughout the entire table). I need for each value in 'Customer ID to only appear once, so I need a single row for each customer ID.

In other words, I'd like for the above table to look like:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------+  
| Customer ID |  Company  | Sales |  
+-------------+-----------+-------+  
|    45678293 | Sears     |    45 |  
|    01928573 | Walmart   |     6 |  
|    29385068 | Fortinoes |     2 |  
|    49582015 | Walmart   |     1 |  
|    19285740 | Target    |    56 |  
|    39506783 | Target    |     4 |    
+-------------+-----------+-------+
```

If anyone knows how I can go about doing this, I'd much appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: `GROUP BY Customer_ID`?

Comment: @Marc B - I don't see how I can use GROUP BY, I don't want to aggregate any of the fields.

Comment: so which company do you want to select, e.g first in alpha order?

Comment: you can group without aggregates, you'll simply get ONE of the grouped-by fields instead of all of them.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - For my purposes, it doesn't matter which company I select. As long as there's only one. I've selected a solution below that worked for me.

Comment: @Marc B - I didn't realize that. Thanks, I'll have to look into that, could be useful in the future. I've selected a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it would have been helpful, if you have put your sql generate that data.

but it might go something like;

```
SELECT customer_id, Max(Company) as company, Count(sales.*) From Customers <your joins and where clause> GROUP BY customer_id
```

Assumes; there are many company and picks out the most number of occurance and the sales data to be in a different table.

Hope this helps.